# Program to make vowels in string uppercase and change letters to next letter in alphabet(i.e. a->b) not working

Tags: javascript, string, join, alphabet

how can I solve this. It is supposed to make all vowels in str capitalized and to change each letter in the alphabet to the next letter in the alphabet(i.e. a -> b, or z->a). It keeps returning "str.join is not a function". Any Help? By the way, it's JavaScript.

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

  str = str.split("");//split() string into array
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;str++){//for loop that checks each letter
    if(str[i]===/[^a-y]/){
      str=str[i].fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
        }else if(str[i]==='z'){
          str[i] = 'a';
        }
    if(str[i] === 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'){
       str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase();
       }

  }

  //modifies letter by adding up in alphabet
  //capitalizes each vowel
  //join() string


  return str.join(); 
}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
LetterChanges(readline());
```

Comment: `str[i]===/[^a-y]/` this looks like a logical error.

Comment: What does readline() do/return?

Comment: First you convert `str` to array, then back to a string with `fromCharCode`. You're mutating. It's no longer an array when you do `str.join`

Comment: To add to @VisioN's comment, this isn't right either `str[i] === 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'`

Comment: readline() inputs the value I type into a text bar. It shouldn't affect the rest of it. This is for one of those online coding websites and LetterChanges(readline()); was put into the program by the website. Just ignore it.

Comment: This line:     'str=str[i].fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);'  is getting error: "TypeError: str[i].fromCharCode is not a function"

Comment: Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you need to read a bit on JavaScript.

This is doesn't do what you think `str[i]===/[^a-y]/`. You should use `str[i].match(/[a-y]/i)`.

This doesn't do what you think: `str[i] === 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'`. It'll always return true. You'll want this `str[i].match(/[aeiou]/i)`.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. And yes, I'm trying to teach myself Javascript. Does === not work when comparing strings? Do I always have to use .match() when comparing strings?

Comment: @user3196340 String.match() finds the matches in strings against the passed regular expression. === does work when comparing strings, but it compares for equality without type coercion, rather than matching a regex.

Answer (score 1):

There are several logical errors in your code, as described in [@Simon Boudrias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143655/1249581) answer.

However just for self-learning here is an alternative solution for your problem:

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/g, function(c) {
    return 'aeiou'.indexOf(c) > -1
        ? c.toUpperCase()
        : String.fromCharCode(Math.max(c.charCodeAt(0) % 122 + 1, 97));
});
```

Comment: @user3196340 Yeah, more than normal.